# I can't get the label values

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def price():
    if am1 != '0':
        price1 = (en1.get())*(pr1.cget('text'))
    if am2 != '0':
        price2 = (en1.get())*(pr2.cget('text'))
    if am3 != '0':
        price3 = (en1.get())*(pr3.cget('text'))
    if am4 != '0':
        price4 = (en1.get())*(pr4.cget('text'))
    if am5 != '0':
        price5 = (en1.get())*(pr5.cget('text'))
    if am6 != '0':
        price6 = (en1.get())*(pr6.cget('text'))
    if am7 != '0':
        price7 = (en1.get())*(pr7.cget('text'))
    if am8 != '0':
        price8 = (en1.get())*(pr8.cget('text'))

    total = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4 + price5 + price6 + price7 + price8
    paymethod = var.get()
    lbme.configure(text=paymethod)
    pricevar.set(total)
    
            

win = Tk()
win.title('McDonald ordering system')
win.geometry('575x425')


lbtitle = Label(win,text='Welcome to McDonald',bg='yellow')
lbtitle.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

f1 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=275,height=200,relief=GROOVE)
f1.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=3)
f1.grid_propagate(0)

f2 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=275,height=200,relief=GROOVE)
f2.grid(row=1,column=1,rowspan=3)
f2.grid_propagate(0)

f3 = Frame(win,bd=2,width=275,height=200,relief=GROOVE)
f3.grid(row=4,column=0,rowspan=3)
f3.grid_propagate(0)

lb1 = Label(f1,text='Big Mac')
lb1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr1 = Label(f1,text='43')
pr1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am1 = IntVar()
en1 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am1,width=5)
en1.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

lb2 = Label(f1,text='Cheeseburger')
lb2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr2 = Label(f1,text='40')
pr2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am2 = IntVar()
en2 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am2,width=5)
en2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

lb3 = Label(f1,text='Nuggets')
lb3.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr2 = Label(f1,text='36')
pr2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am3 = IntVar()
en3 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am3,width=5)
en3.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

lb4 = Label(f1,text='Chicken')
lb4.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr2 = Label(f1,text='33')
pr2.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am4 = IntVar()
en4 = Entry(f1,textvariable=am4,width=5)
en4.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

lb5 = Label(f2,text='Cheesecake')
lb5.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr2 = Label(f2,text='29')
pr2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am5 = IntVar()
en5 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am5,width=5)
en5.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

lb6 = Label(f2,text='Chocolate Cake')
lb6.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr2 = Label(f2,text='28')
pr2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am6 = IntVar()
en6 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am6,width=5)
en6.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

lb7 = Label(f2,text='McFlurry')
lb7.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr2 = Label(f2,text='13')
pr2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am7 = IntVar()
en7 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am7,width=5)
en7.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

lb8 = Label(f2,text='Pepsi')
lb8.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

pr2 = Label(f2,text='8')
pr2.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

am8 = IntVar()
em8 = Entry(f2,textvariable=am8,width=5)
em8.grid(row=3,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)

var = StringVar()
var.set('Cash')

ch1 = Radiobutton(f3,text='Cash',value='Cash',variable=var)
ch1.grid(row=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=W)


ch2 = Radiobutton(f3,text='Octopus',value='Octopus',variable=var)
ch2.grid(row=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=W)


ch3 = Radiobutton(f3,text='Credit Card',value='Credit Card',variable=var)
ch3.grid(row=2,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=W)


ch4 = Radiobutton(f3,text='WeChat Pay',value='WeChat Pay',variable=var)
ch4.grid(row=3,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=W)

btn = Button(win,text='Confirm',command=price)
btn.grid(row=4,column=1,)

lbpay = Label(win,text='Pay Method')
lbpay.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W,padx=10)

lbme = Label(win,text='')
lbme.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=E,padx=10)


lbpr = Label(win,text='Price')
lbpr.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=W,padx=10)

pricevar = StringVar()
enpr = Entry(win,textvariable=pricevar)
enpr.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=E,padx=5)


Error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\Python Projects Fun\fastfood_app.py", line 6, in price
    price1 = (en1.get())*(pr1.cget('text'))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'*
```

My aim is to multiply the label price value with the amount number in entry however I got the above error. I may want to ask does label have the get function and also how to change the label text? Is there anything I am missing? I searched thorougly the book and do not know what method should I use to get the value of the label

Comment: yoou cant multiply strings you need to convert them first into integers with int()

Comment: Where should int put?

Comment: like int(en1.get())*int(pr1.cget('text'))

Comment: I changed to int then it mentioned error that unsupported operand type

Comment: I've made the exact same thing and it runs. Are you aware that you need to do it for each line not just for en1 and pr1 ?

Comment: So I should change int(en1.get())*int(pr1.cget('text')) and so on..?

Comment: of course it is the same failure in each line.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot multiply str by int. I've fixed your code by adding `int` infront of your strings:

```
def price():
    if am1 != '0':
        price1 = (en1.get())*int(pr1.cget('text'))
    if am2 != '0':
        price2 = (en1.get())*int(pr2.cget('text'))
    if am3 != '0':
        price3 = (en1.get())*int(pr3.cget('text'))
    if am4 != '0':
        price4 = (en1.get())*int(pr4.cget('text'))
    if am5 != '0':
        price5 = (en1.get())*int(pr5.cget('text'))
    if am6 != '0':
        price6 = (en1.get())*int(pr6.cget('text'))
    if am7 != '0':
        price7 = (en1.get())*int(pr7.cget('text'))
    if am8 != '0':
        price8 = (en1.get())*int(pr8.cget('text'))
```

you have some definitions errors as well but they might not yet be defined in your whole code. I'll leave you to it.

EDIT: I just saw the comments this is already fixed...